# reCAPTCHA widget is not showing

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, recaptcha

As per [documentation of firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth?authuser=1#use-the-recaptcha-widget) for using re-CAPTCHA.
I created a `div` inside sign-up form.
`<div id="recaptcha-container"></div>`
and used the code as given in documentation -

```
import { getAuth, RecaptchaVerifier } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-auth.js";

const auth = getAuth();
window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container', {}, auth);
```

But when I reload my `sign-up.php` page, my captcha didn't show. Even I didn't get any error in console.

**Why am I not able to see captcha layout ?**

Answer (score 0):

I think you should specify the size to normal, try this:

```
import { getAuth, RecaptchaVerifier } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.2/firebase-auth.js";

const auth = getAuth();
window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container', {'size': 'normal'}, auth);
```

Comment: It still is not showing.

Answer (score 0):

pass the firebase config instance in getAuth

```
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
     import { getAuth, RecaptchaVerifier } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.1/firebase-auth.js";
    
            const auth = getAuth(app);
            window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container', { 'size': 'normal' }, auth);
            recaptchaVerifier.render();
```

for me also same problem after pass this firbaseConfig instanse it shows the reCAPTCHA widget and render it

Comment: This did not work for me either